# WildFly - Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40"" was unexpected at this time

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm trying to start up WildFly 8 with a custom start.bat file that calls standalone.bat and then also a custom property file. When I run my start.bat I get this error in the command line:

```
C:\PWServer8>propworks_start.bat
C:\PWServer8\bin>call standalone.bat -P=../propworks/conf/propworks.properties  -b 10.10.100.122
Calling "C:\PWServer8\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40"" was unexpected at this time.
```

I've done a search for "was unexpected at this time" within all the files in my WildFly folder but nothing turned up so I couldn't pinpoint where the error is coming from. Here is my custom start.bat and afterwards is my property file. If anyone knows what's going on it would be a big help.

**propworks_start.bat**

```
C:
cd C:\PWServer8\bin
SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40"
call standalone.bat -P=../propworks/conf/propworks.properties  -b 10.10.100.122
```

**propworks.properties**

```
#PROPworks Configuration Properties
#Wed Jun 18 17:18:03 EDT 2014
propworks.bind.address=10.10.100.122
propworks.database.class=Oracle10g
propworks.database.connection.sql=select 1 From Dual
propworks.database.desc=support@mcosrvorcl001
propworks.database.dialect=com.airit.propworks.server.dialect.PWOracleDialect
propworks.database.driver=oracle
propworks.database.password=-5522f65bbe2cc1c6
propworks.database.schema=uc2014
propworks.database.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@10.10.201.10\:1521\:bsdev
propworks.database.user=uc2014
propworks.http.port=8080
propworks.indb.use=NONE
propworks.jdk.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_40
propworks.messaging.port=5445
propworks.remoting.port=4447
archiver.enabled=N
orafin.database.driver=oracle
orafin.database.password=
orafin.database.user=
org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ.jndiURL=java\:/propworksDS
org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ_NO_TX.jndiURL=java\:/quartzDS
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=QUARTZ
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource=QUARTZ_NO_TX
org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL=SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS WHERE LOCK_NAME \= ? FOR UPDATE
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export=false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy=false
org.quartz.scheduler.xaTransacted=false
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=3
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=9
psfin.database.driver=oracle
psfin.database.password=
psfin.database.user=
pwarchiver.database.driver=oracle
pwarchiver.database.password=
pwarchiver.database.user=
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two solutions:

1) move java to folder that does not have spaces in it.
2) double quote path when you set it

```
SET JAVA_HOME=""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40""
```

Answer (score 0):

add `\` similar below :

> SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40`\`

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by the space in front of C:\Program , so what u need to do is changing your JAVA file in c:program files \java to another file without spaces , and then in top of your file write :
SET JAVA_HOME=""NEW DIRECTORY WITHOUT SPACE\Java\jdk1.7.0_40""
this worked for me.